# Is Gorlin's sign hereditary?

Tags: human-genetics

"Gorlin's Sign" is the ability to touch the tip of the nose with the tongue.  [It is present in half of people with Ehlers-Danlos syndrome, but is also present in a minority of people without that disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorlin_sign): among them, both me and one of my sons.

Is it known whether this trait is hereditary?  If so, is it a simple genetic trait (e.g., is it sex-linked, Mendelian)?

Comment: Can you please link to your source when you state `It is present in half of people with Ehlers-Danlos syndrome, but is also present in a minority of people without that disorder`? This source may be a good starting point to try to answer your question.

Comment: @Remi.b - I just added source of that statement (Wikipedia).